# Environment variables, JAR and batch files

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, jar

I have a quick question.
I'm trying to run a JAR file that gets data from environment variables.
If I open a CMD window and set each environment variable manually using the `set` command  and then run the JAR file with `java -jar MyFile.jar` everything works.
However, when I create a batch file containing the exact commands I executed before, the JAR file doesn't find the environment variables. I tried using `cmd /k` after all of the commands to try and access the environment variables with `echo` and they work. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? Thank you.
Edit:
Here's my batch file:

```
SET ATR1=ATR1_VALUE  
SET ATR2=ATR2_VALUE  
SET ATR3=ATR3_VALUE  
JAVA -JAR MyFile.jar
```

Using this file my JAR doesn't access the environment variables successfully.
However if I run each line on it's own the JAR file works.
I'm using `System.getenv()` to access the environment variables in my code.
I've tried using `setx` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: `set` sets variables that lasts only for the current session.If you want environment variables that will survive between sessions check `setx` command.

Comment: There are two spaces after each value. If that is really your code, they are part of your variables (don't know if that makes any difference with your java) To avoid it, use `set "ATR1=ATR1_VALUE"`

Comment: Those two spaces are there because they are interpreted as a newline. They are not in the actual file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

```
SET "ATR=ATR1_VALUE"
```

or

```
SETX ATR "ATR1_VALUE"
```